# Is there a formal name for this recursive sequence?

Tags: recursion, computability

Suppose I have two numbers, A,B. Suppose I am allowed to add them together, but can only add one at a time. So, for example:

```
Seed Case: (A,    B)
Step 1:    (A+B,  B)  or  (A,   A+B)
Step 2:    (A+2B, B)  or  (A+B, A+2B)  or  (2A+B,  B+A)  or  (A, B+2A)
Step 3:    (A+3B, B)  or  (A+B, 2A+3B) or  (2A+3B, A+2B) or ...
... etc
```

I am wondering if anyone knows of the formal name of this sequence, as I am trying to find information on its characteristics. Specifically, I am interested in the minimum distance between the base case and a given term (in terms of intermediate additions which must occur). But I don't know where to start researching it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll write $a$ and $b$ in lowercase. Let $X = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$ and $Y = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right]$. Each expression you describe here can be obtained by starting from the vector $v = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a \\ b \end{array} \right]$ and repeatedly applying $X$ or $Y$, since

$$Xv = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a + b \\ b \end{array} \right], Yv = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a \\ a + b \end{array} \right].$$

So the terms in Step 2 correspond to $X^2 v, XY v, YX v, Y^2 v$, for example. In general you are looking at the [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) generated by these two matrices, and you want to compute the [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) of an element of this monoid (the shortest word in $X$ and $Y$ that produces it).

This is actually quite easy, for the following reason: if you start from an expression $(n_1 a + m_1 b, n_2 a + m_2 b)$ (equivalently, a matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} n_1 & m_1 \\ n_2 & m_2 \end{array} \right]$) and want to work backwards to the base $(a, b)$, given that this is possible there is a *unique* way to do it at each step, because exactly one of the two expressions can be subtracted from the other and not vice versa. For example, given $(a + b, 2a + 3b)$ in Step 3,

- the first term can be subtracted from the second but not vice versa, so the previous step must be $(a + b, a + 2b)$. Then,
- again the first term can be subtracted from the second but not vice versa, so the previous step must be $(a + b, b)$. Then,
- the second term can be subtracted from the first but not vice versa, so the previous step must be $(a, b)$ and we're done.

In other words, the sequence of $X$s and $Y$s generating a given expression is unique; this says that $X$ and $Y$ generate the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on two generators.

When performing these reductions the coefficients $n_i, m_i$ are being subjected to a slight variation of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) so that's a place you can look for bounds on the total number of steps; generally speaking they will be logarithmic although there'll be edge cases, e.g. $(a + nb, b)$ takes $n$ steps. You get basically the Euclidean algorithm if you decide that adding $n$ copies of one of the numbers to the other counts as one step and this simplifies the counting of the total number of steps.

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful and gives me exactly the background information I need to learn more.